# Получить минимальное и максимальное значение в каждой группе

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица sales и calls. Связь между ними следующая: sales.phone = calls.caller_phone. одному sales может соответствовать несколько calls. В calls есть поле даты calltime. Нужен запрос на получение sales.id совместно с id-шниками calls с минимальным и максимальным calltime.
То есть должно получится что то вроде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент у меня получился только запрос на получение отдельно id-шников с минимальным calltime, потом повторный запрос на получение максимальных calltime. Но я думаю должно быть решение в один запрос.
Вот мой запрос:

```
select 
    sale_stat.sale_id,sale_stat.call_id 
from 
    (select sales.id as sale_id,calls.id as call_id,
     calls.calltime,rank() 
over 
    (partition by sales.id 
    order by calls.calltime desc) 
from 
    sales,calls 
where 
    sales.phone = calls.caller_phone) as sale_stat 
where 
    rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from sales
join lateral (
    select id, calltime
    from calls where caller_phone = phone
    order by calltime limit 1
) firstcall on true
join lateral (
    select id, calltime
    from calls where caller_phone = phone
    order by calltime desc limit 1
) lastcall on true
```

Для `calls` релевантен индекс `btree(caller_phone, calltime)`

Postgresql 9.3 и выше. Время от времени путаю asc и desc, проверьте.

```
with firstcall as (
    select distinct on (caller_phone) caller_phone as phone, calltime, id 
    from calls
    order by caller_phone, calltime
), lastcall as (
    select distinct on (caller_phone) caller_phone as phone, calltime, id 
    from calls
    order by caller_phone, calltime desc
)
select * from sales
join firstcall using(phone)
join lastcall using(phone)
```

Сгодится для музейных версий и не сильно производительно - двойной fullscan по calls, но ещё варианты писать лениво.

Comment: А первый вариант по производительности норм? А мой вариант с двумя отдельными запросами быстрее должен быть или не стоит?

Comment: Удвоенное число index scan от числа строк в выборе sales. Может быть адекватно, может быть печально, надо смотреть на конкретный `explain (analyze,buffers)`. Может быть разумнее в sales (или рядом с ним) закинуть FK на первую и последнюю строку и обновлять триггером.

Comment: Плюс не очень представляю себе что именно будет делать executor с оконными функциями в исходном запросе, может он получится дороже.